# uibezierpath subtract path to draw patial rectangle

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I want to use uibezierpath to draw sth like the followling pic.But I only find some api add whole rect ,can I use some tricks to draw patial rect

[image: sam]

Comment: You might consider drawing the whole rect, then drawing opaque white (or whatever color) over the portion of the rect you don't want.

Comment: Try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136400/drawing-a-line-with-bezierpath-using-cashapelayer-object?rq=1